# If $\alpha\ne0$ and $\beta\ne0$, show that $E_{ij}(\alpha)$ and $E_{mn}(\beta)$ commute iff $i\ne n$ and $j\ne m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**NOTE :** $E_{xy}(c)$ is the elementary matrix corresponding to the row operation, adding $c$ times the $y^{th}$ row to the $x^{th}$ row ($x\ne y$).

> **Question:** If $\alpha\ne0$ and $\beta\ne0$, **show that** $E_{ij}(\alpha)$ and $E_{mn}(\beta)$ commute iff $i\ne n$ and $j\ne m$.

I tried to understand what it means using an example:
$$
    E_{21}(1)=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix},
E_{31}(2)=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Now,
$$
    E_{31}(2)\cdot E_{21}(1)=E_{31}(2)\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$$$
E_{21}(1)\cdot E_{31}(2)=E_{21}(1)\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
$\Rightarrow E_{31}(2)\cdot E_{21}(1)=E_{21}(1)\cdot E_{31}(2)$
**My approach :**

Suppose $E_{ij}(\alpha)$ and $E_{mn}(\beta)$ commute. Then,

$E_{ij}(\alpha)\cdot E_{mn}(\beta)=E_{mn}(\beta)\cdot E_{ij}(\alpha)$

$\Rightarrow (E_{ij}(\alpha)\cdot E_{mn}(\beta))A=(E_{mn}(\beta)\cdot E_{ij}(\alpha))A\quad$ for some matrix $A$

$\Rightarrow E_{ij}(\alpha)(E_{mn}(\beta)\cdot A)=E_{mn}(\beta)(E_{ij}(\alpha)\cdot A)$

> Using basic definition, I can see that this is possible iff $m\ne j$ and $n\ne i$ but I don't know if this is enough for a "formal" proof.

Comment: $E_{ij}(\alpha)=\operatorname{Id}+\alpha E_{ij}$ where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with a 1 in the $(i,j)$-place and 0 everywhere. Maybe this can help

Comment: @AleTolcachier Proceeding, we can conclude that the two commute iff $E_{ij}\cdot E_{mn}=E_{mn}\cdot E_{ij}$. After this I can take cases and see that this happens iff $i\ne n$ and $j\ne m$. Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: That was exactly what I have in mind. Indeed, $E_{ij} E_{mn}=E_{in}\delta_{jm}$ and $E_{mn} E_{ij}=E_{mj} \delta_{i n}$.

Comment: @AleTolcachier I am a little confused now.. what is $\delta$? Could you please write an answer, I think I might have carried out some steps incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E_{ij}(\alpha)=\operatorname{Id}+\alpha E_{ij}$ where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with a 1 in the $(i,j)$-place and 0 everywhere.

$E_{ij}(\alpha)$ and $E_{mn}(\beta)$ commute

$\begin{align}\iff&(\operatorname{Id}+\alpha E_{ij})(\operatorname{Id}+\beta E_{mn})=(\operatorname{Id}+\beta E_{mn})(\operatorname{Id}+\alpha E_{ij})
\\\iff& \operatorname{Id}+\alpha E_{ij}+\beta E_{mn}+\alpha\beta E_{ij}E_{mn}=\operatorname{Id}+\alpha E_{ij}+\beta E_{mn}+\alpha\beta E_{mn}E_{ij}\\ \iff&E_{ij}E_{mn}=E_{mn}E_{ij} 
\end{align}$

In the last step I use $\alpha\neq 0\neq \beta$. But As I said in the comments, $E_{ij}E_{mn}=E_{in}\delta_{jm}$ where $\delta_{jm}=\begin{cases}1&j=m\\0&j\neq m\end{cases}$  (Kronecker's delta) (This can be checked using definition of multiplication)

So $E_{ij}E_{mn}=E_{mn}E_{ij}\iff E_{in}\delta_{jm}=E_{mj}\delta_{in}$.

Now, if $i\neq n$ and $m\neq j$ we have 0=0 so $E_{ij}(\alpha)$ and $E_{mn}(\beta)$ commute.

In any of the other cases ($i=n, m\neq j$ or $i\neq n, m=j$ or $i=n, m=j$) they don't commute.

Comment: My answer shows (If I'm correct) that the result as it is stated now is false because if $i=j$ then $E_{ij}(\alpha)$ and $E_{mn}(\beta)$ commute even when $i=n$ and $m=j$ so maybe you must assume $i\neq j$?

Comment: I must not have mentioned this; by definition $E_{ij}(\alpha)$ is defined for $i\ne j$. Then, the result is true.

Comment: Oh, you're right, it makes no sense $i=j$. I lose the focus by doing the algebraic manipulations, I will edit the final part of the answer then.

Comment: Also I mention that the formula $E_{ij}E_{mn}=E_{in}\delta_{jm}$ appears sometimes, It is worthwhile keeping it I think.